# Sql values in column

Tags: sql

I have a table `tblIndex` with following values:

```
indID   indDesc  indNo
  1     Desc1     999
  2     Desc2     999
  3     Desc3     995
  4     Desc4     995
  5     Desc5     999
```

I want to `SELECT` three rows into one row `where indNo=999`... like below:

```
indDesc  indDesc   indDesc   indNo
Desc1    Desc2     Desc5      999
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Also, do you always need 3 rows? What should happen if there are more or fewer rows with the same indNo value?

Comment: you could use cursers, but I hate them.

Comment: @bluefeet: Using SqlServer 2005.

Comment: @Ken: It may return more then 3 rows depending on data in the table.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're actually want to get a single value for all records.
If you're using SQL-Server you could create a [scalar-valued-function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131043.aspx) like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getIndexDescriptionByNumber]
(
    @indNo int,
    @delimiter varchar(5)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @indDesc VARCHAR(8000);
    SELECT  @indDesc = COALESCE(@indDesc + @delimiter, '') + table.indDesc
    FROM    table
    WHERE   table.indNo = @indNo
    ORDER BY indDesc ;

    return @indDesc  ;
END
```

You would call it in this way:

```
SELECT dbo.getIndexDescriptionByNumber(999, ' ') AS indDesc;
```

Result:

```
indDesc
Desc1 Desc2 Desc5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, look for [PIVOT tables](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx)